# Update table with each input character

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've just asked a question on how to refresh an element without refreshing your page. I've been learning ajax for some hours now, but I'm having trouble getting any implemented.

So what I want to do is this:

Refresh a table containing mainly sql executions, for which I need the input value.

To update it I use `onkeyup="Search();"` which then forwards my value to another php page.

```
<input type="text" id="IDsearch" onkeyup="Search()" autofocus>
```

I know I can get this value on a php page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Search() {
        var inputValue = $('#IDsearch').val();

        $.post('testAjaxJquery.php', {postname: inputValue},
        function (data) {
            $('#IDsearch').val(data)
        });
    }
</script>
```

and in PHP (`testAjaxJquery.php`)

```
<?php

$searchValue = $_POST['postname'];
echo $searchValue;
?>
```

The problem here is: I don't know how to use the retrieved value and update my existing table with it, without a page refresh. I tried putting all of the code inside a new php file and using `$("#refreshOnSearch").load("refresh.php");`, no luck.

The essence is: Once a letter is typed, I need an updated version of my table.

I guess you could say I am trying to replicate https://datatables.net/index.

Comment: Problem is unclear. You don;t know the name of table? You can't write sql queries? or what?

Comment: Edited my question, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Open developer's console and check for errors there.

Comment: There are none, I don't have any table update code yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with looking inside your `$.post function`.

Then inspect `data` using `console.log(data)` or `debugger` and looking at what data is. It's possible data is an object and you are trying to set `#IDsearch` to an object instead of a `string` or `int`.

If that is the case you will want to do something like `$('#IDsearch').val(data.response);`

Comment: My question is hard to ask.. I think you misunderstood. There is nothing wrong with my function; it works perfectly. I don't know how to use refresh my table, without refreshing the page. I also need to use this new value to update the table contents.

Comment: Can you post an example of your table and the data that is being returned

Comment: if you are trying to update multiple values in the table without a page refresh you're going to have to return all of those values in `data` and update them in the dom with jquery either individually or incrementally

Comment: or rebuild the table each time